# How do you make an image scroll partly? Halfway between position:fixed and position:absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I want a background image to move up/down as the visitor scrolls, but not scroll with the page.  It's neither fixed to the screen nor scrolling with the rest of the content.  It's in between position:fixed and position:absolute.

Example: http://www.madebyhangar.com/
See how where it says "We take pride in the work we do and we do it with extra care" the background image moves as you scroll but it does not fully scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I inspected the page with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and what happens is that for the `div` element using a `background-image`, `background-position` style is changed (via scroll event I suppose). This is how the effect works.

Comment: I'm not familiar with scroll events. Can you sample me some code?

Comment: @Nathan Google is your friend. Anyway, a simple page inspect reveals they're use Stellar.js http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/docs/

Comment: in case someone need it, I found this [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/4eBDE/55/)